# Covariance Matrix for Time Series

Tags: r, time-series, econometrics, covariance-matrix

I'm trying to investigate how events affect the stock market through econo-physics and I came across a paper that uses the co-variance matrix.

What I don't understand is how such a matrix can be formed with one time series. The paper says:

> We study here the behaviour of the first three eigenvalues (λ1, λ2,
>   λ3) and their ratio [(λ1/λ2), (λ1/λ3), (λ2/λ3)] of the co-variance matrices
>   of the original return series and of those rebuilt from wavelet
>   components for emerging and mature markets.

How can I replicate this if I'm looking at a series like the DJIA?

`cov(ts)` simply returns a single value.

EDIT: The link to the paper provided in the question is not working anymore. It seems the author was referring to the paper *Sharkasi, Adel and Crane, Martin and Ruskin, Heather J. and Matos, Jose A. (2006) The reaction of stock markets to crashes: a comparison study between emerging and mature markets using wavelet transforms. Physica A: Statistical Mechanics and its Applications, 368 (2). pp. 511-521. ISSN 0378-4371*. [I found another working link here](http://doras.dcu.ie/14858/)

Comment: Are you sure they're not looking at a vector-valued time series? Would be good to include a citation and link to the paper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a set of time series $t_1,...,t_n$, the Covariance Matrix is as follows:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
Var(t_1) & Cov(t_1,t_2) & \cdots & Cov(t_1,t_n) \\
Cov(t_2,t_1) & Var(t_2) & \cdots & Cov(t_2,t_n) \\ 
\cdots \\
Cov(t_n,t_1) & Cov(t_n,t_2) & \cdots & Var(t_n) \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

It looks like your inputing only one time series, so the output is just a 1x1 matrix:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
Var(t_1)
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Of course, a 1x1 matrix has only one eigenvalue & one eigenvector

Answer (score 4):

They can estimate a covariance matrix because they're working with vector-valued time series. This is a time series where the value at each time point is a vector, rather than a single value. $x(t) = [x_1(t), ..., x_n(t)]$. You could also think of this as a set of multiple time series (one for each element of the vector).

Equation 1 in the paper says exactly how they're getting the covariance matrix.